# Lambda custom al2 runtime with golang, timing out init phase

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

I've an existing lambda function with go1.x runtime, which working fine with sqs triggers. Trying to update the function to use new provided.al2 runtime using the instructions here.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/migrating-aws-lambda-functions-from-the-go1-x-runtime-to-the-custom-runtime-on-amazon-linux-2/

Have updated the binary with *bootstrap* name, with this updated build command.
`GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o bootstrap`

[image: New runtime settings]

After updating this new package and changing runtime, execution is always timing out in the init phase.

INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 10008.47 ms Phase: init Status: timeout

INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 60060.47 ms Phase: invoke Status: error Error Type: Runtime.Unknown

Same code works when I change binary to main and switch back to go1.x runtime.
can someone help?

Edit:

Issue is resolved after updating aws-lambda-go library to latest.

Old version is working perfectly fine with Go 1.x runtime. But to use custom amazon linux 2 runtime, had to update the library to latest version.

Comment: I'm getting this exact error with my NextJs deployments in Vercel.
I've tried changing runtimes, but to no avail. It's times like this when I wished I had more control over my deployments...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that the github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go library used in existing code is not compatible with new al2 runtime. Have updated this library to the latest version and init timeout error isssue is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you forgot updating the lambda handler setting?
See „change the handler“ here: https://www.go-on-aws.com/lambda-go/lambda_function/create-console-custom/

Comment: Handler is already updated to new binary bootstrap as shown in the question description